# Tag in Tag Javascript Replace

Tags: javascript, html, regex

```
$format_search =  [
            /\[QUOTE\](.*?)\[\/QUOTE\]/ig
]
$format_replace = [
            '<div class="quote">$1</div>'
]
```

These are search and replace codes. By using

```
 str = str.replace($format_search[0], $format_replace[0])
```

I replace tags with html div codes. It works good except quote in a quote. If somebody quotes a quoted text in forum such as

```
[quote][quote]Hi[/quote] Hello[/quote]
```

instead of this one:

```
<div class="quote"><div class="quote">Hi</div> Hello</div>
```

I get this output:

```
<div class="quote">[quote]Hi</div> Hello[/quote]
```

it finds first [/quote] and accept it as a closure for the first quote. How can I make the code search [/quote] from end. Is there any another solution?

Comment: If they can be nested like that, like HTML, then you can't do this with regex alone; proper parsing is your only option, [just like HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/157247).

Comment: [try this](https://gist.github.com/Pruthvi-Raj/19bfd8d5a30c8a13b331)